# AOF file becomes empty when I perform BGREWRITEAOF in Redis

Tags: redis

I have a Redis instance in which I have enabled both Snapshot and AOF.
Notable configs are:

```
#snapshot
save 60 5
dbfilename "dump.rdb"
dir "/Ankit/redis_installation/redis-stable"

#aof
appendonly yes
appendfilename "appendonly.aof"
appenddirname "appendonlydir"
aof-use-rdb-preamble yes
```

I started Redis instance and set some values to the same keys and then performed BGREWRITEAOF to expect that those multiple SET commands would be truncated.
To my surprise when I cat the .aof file I saw that it is empty. I have some data in a .rdb file instead. (Note that this is not the rdb file created by the regular snapshot)

```
[root@kafka1 redis-stable]# ll appendonlydir/
total 8
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 100 Jan 13 12:56 appendonly.aof.3.base.rdb
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   0 Jan 13 12:56 appendonly.aof.3.incr.aof
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  88 Jan 13 12:56 appendonly.aof.manifest
```

If you see, the .aof file size is 0. And what are those 2 extra files (`appendonly.aof.3.base.rdb` and `appendonly.aof.manifest`)

In that case if my Redis starts, it will not have an AOF file to replay the data and also it has 2 RDB files now (mentioned below). Which one will it use to restore data?

1. dump.rdb: Created using the regular snapshot
2. appendonly.aof.3.base.rdb: I don't know why is this created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Redis 7.0, it use muliti-part AOF format, which includes 3 types of files:

- base file: A snapshot of the dataset since AOF is created (or rewritten). There's only one base file. Once AOF file is rewritten, a new base file is created. It might be a RDB file or an AOF file.
- incr file: new commands (AOF file) since the base file is created. There may be multiple incr files.
- manifest file: File used to track (base/incr) files, orders and types of base file and incr file.

> when I cat the .aof file I saw that it is empty. I have some data in a .rdb file instead.

Because the rewritten result is the base file in RDB format, i.e. appendonly.aof.3.base.rdb. There's no new commands sent to Redis since the rewritten, so the incr AOF file, i.e. appendonly.aof.3.incr.aof, is empty.

> In that case if my Redis starts, it will not have an AOF file to replay the data and also it has 2 RDB files now (mentioned below). Which one will it use to restore data?

No. It has both an AOF file (with multi-part format, and the base file's format is RDB) and a RDB file, and it will use AOF file when your restart it.